# Can I use the Union and Optional types from the typing module when creating a dataclass?

Tags: python-3.x, python-dataclasses

I want to use the `Union` and `Optional` types when creating a dataclass.
Can I use these types safely?

E.g.:

```
@dataclass
class Car:
    year: int
    owner: Optional[str]
    engine: Union[Engine1, Engine2]
```

Comment: [Annotations can be any python expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#annassign).  What do you mean by "safely"?

Comment: The documentation for the `dataclasses` module and various tutorials on the Internet use only "simple" types, such as `str`, `float`, `int`, SomeClass, `Any`.

Comment: As a side note, if you want to verify that your type hints are correct, you should use a type checker, like [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/), [pyre](https://github.com/facebook/pyre-check) or [pyright](https://github.com/Microsoft/pyright).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can. First off, annotations in python don't do anything by themselves. From other languages you might expect that declaring a variable as `int` will lead to an error if it is instantiated as, say, a string, but that just isn't the case in python.

Annotations are only used by third party libraries or tools, like your IDE when it gives you hints, or [`mypy`](http://mypy-lang.org/) when it does a static type analysis of your code.

So you should use a kind of annotation that your tools work well with, and from my personal experience that would mean to use the type annotations from the `typing` module over the basic types.

---

While there is no declarative statement on what you *must* use, [here is a thread](https://github.com/ericvsmith/dataclasses/issues/2) discussing default dataclass types including ericvsmith (the author of the dataclasses module) and gvanrossum (the author of python), and they agree that `typing.Any` should be preferred over `object`.

I assume the dataclass documentation uses basic python types in order to not place too much of a burden of knowledge on the reader. You can use dataclasses just fine without knowing anything about the `typing` module after all, and once you are comfortable with how dataclasses work, you're probably going to run into and appreciate the additional power of using `typing`'s annotations anyway.